# How to return Google Image search results in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, google-custom-search

The google image search API has been deprecated and Google suggests using the  custom search API instead, however when I attempt to create a custom search engine at cse.google.com it requires a "site to search", instead of just searching the web like google does. I would love a "hello world" of how to get the urls of the results of a google image search such as "cats".

Comment: Have you try before asking this question. Please share your code.

Comment: same question here, did you resolve this? I just need to generate a web form with a query and a header to send to google to return google images. i need an example google image url query from a user agent.